# Can I aggregate over gradients in tensorflow-federated?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

Currently, the tensorflow's federated_learn seem to only include things like federated_averaging that work on the model's trainable variables. How would I go about implementing algorithms that require the gradients for aggregation at the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As of release `0.2.0`, TensorFlow Federated includes an implementation of FedSGD ([`tff.learning.build_federated_sgd_process()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/build_federated_sgd_process)), as described by the paper:

*Communication-Efficient Learning of Deep Networks from Decentralized Data*
H. Brendan McMahan, Eider Moore, Daniel Ramage, Seth Hampson, Blaise Aguera y Arcas. AISTATS 2017.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05629

Code can be found in [`tensorflow_federated/python/learning/federated_sgd.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/federated_sgd.py), which shows aggregating gradients on the client and sending back an aggregated gradient to the server.

Comment: Thank you. though I did not manage to make 'build_federated_sgd_process' run without exceptions with tff@0.4.0, do you know of any simple usage examples? (couldn't make tests in the repo pass either)

Comment: All unit tests should have been passing before tagging the `0.4.0` release. If you're experiencing errors raised in `//tensorflow_federated/python/learning/:federated_sgd_test` in a clean `0.4.0` repo, could you open a issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues?

Comment: I'm experiencing many errors on windows, I think it's more related to bazel and testing framework than it is to tff (did manage to compile protobuf, but I'm getting many exceptions)... I'll open issues. but in any case I'll greatly appreciate a more straight forward usage example (without bazel and pytest) Thank you! @zachary-garrett

Comment: Blaze and pytest are only needed when building TFF from source, which is currently only supported on Linux and MacOS. Do you need to build from source? Version `0.5.0` was released very recently and can be installed with pip. Not sure if it works in a windows environment though.